# How to extract dataframes from this object in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dataset, tidyverse

I have an dataframe with this type:

```
glimpse(df)

Rows: 11
Columns: 32
$ `2020-02-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-03-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-04-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-05-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-06-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-07-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-08-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-09-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-10-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-11-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2020-12-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2021-01-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2021-02-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2021-03-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
$ `2021-04-01` <named list> [<<matrix[88 x 100]>>, <<matrix[25 x 100]>>, <<arr…
```

How can I convert for month to month datasets in R ?

Comment: Can you edit your question?  What does "convert for month to month" mean?  Are you try to split the eleven columns into 11 separate data frames? What would the output of one of those frames look like?

Comment: Exactly @langtang, I need to split the 32 columns in 32 separated df´s...

Comment: You can try `split.default(df,1:ncol(df))`, but that just splits the 32-column frame into a list of 32 separate 1-column data frames..  Can you paste the output of `dput(df[[1]])` into the question, or make a small reproducible example. Also, can you show what is the desired structure of one of your resulting 32 frames?

Comment: Also, could you provide the content of your data.frame? That would be helpful

Comment: @langtang the ``split.default(df,1:ncol(df))`` or the ``dput(df[[1]])`` takes too long to run...I canceled the execution...did you have some alternative way ?

Comment: @EmmanuelHamel here is the ```head(df)``` output: 
 
 ```
2020-02-01
<named list>
model <list [6]> 
X_train <dbl[,13,88] [2,494 × 13 × 88]> 
X_test <dbl[,13,88] [3,180 × 13 × 88]> 
df_input <S3: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame> 
index_test <S3: pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex> 
window <int [1]> 
```